# Where is wrong in my proof? For all finite dimensional field extension we have $H’’=H$ for all subgroups of Galois group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

$F$ is a finite dimensional field extension of $K$. $G$ is the Galois group of $F$. For all intermediate field $E$, $E’$ is the fixing group and for all subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H’$ is the fixed field. Let $0$ be the trivial subgroup and then $0’ = F, 0’’=F’=0$ Since $H \le H’’$ we have
$$\vert H \vert \le \vert H’’ \vert = [H’’ : 0’’] \le [0’:H’] \le [H:0] = \vert H \vert$$

Therefore $H = H’’$ which is ridiculous. Then what’s wrong with my proof?

Comment: $H = H''$ is not ridiculous, it is the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. The proof is that $E$ is the subfield fixed by $Gal(F/E)$.

Comment: @reuns But I never assumed that the extension is Galois extension, which is necessary for Galois theory to hold.

Answer (score 1):

It is the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

If you start with $H\le G$ then $H = Gal(F/F^H)$ and $F/F^H$ is Galois.

For the other subfields  $K\subset E\subset F$ with $E\not\supset F^G$ then $Gal(F/E) \subset G $ thus $F^{Gal(F/E)} \supset F^G$, but it is still true that $Gal(F/F^{Gal(F/E)}) = Gal(F/E)$

(the proof is that $Gal(F/E)=Gal(F/F^GE)$ where $F/F^GE$ is Galois)

Comment: But $H$ may not be $Gal(F/E)$ for any $E$

Comment: $H = Gal(F/F^H)$ this is the fundamental theorem

Comment: the fundamental theorem requires that the extension is Galois, which I haven’t assumed

Comment: You are missing the fundamental theorem. It is easy to prove that for a finite subgroup $H\le Aut(F)$ then $F/F^H$ is Galois : it is normal and separable because for all $a\in F$, $\prod_{b\in Ha} (x-b)\in F^H[x]$. Conversely it is easy to prove that for $L/M$ normal and separable then $M = L^{Gal(L/M)}$ : $M\subset L^{Gal(L/M)}$ and for $a\in L-M$ with $b$ a conjugate, extending the isomorphism $M(a)\to M(b)$ gives an automorphism not fixing $a$.